# How to create a custom shape out of cubes? (using a 3d array)

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, shapes

So i want to create a cube with smaller cubes, but so it looks more like a sphere. Like for a game that consists of cubes, like Minecraft. I came up with the idea of a shape like this. ["spheric cube"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2gT1.png)

Before this, i was creating just a normal cube with 3 "for" loops, row by row. (its just a normal 3d int array with "1" and "0" values) So if i do my "sphere" the same way, there's so much elements to skip and, since the cube is 13x13, its 169 rows... so much code - it looks like a mess. Is there some different way i can do that?

Comment: So my question is too generic? I need to provide code? Sorry this is my first and i cant really properly describe my problem.. i just wanted to know how experienced programmers handle shapes like these. I didnt get "codereview" part, what is this? Thanks for replying though, very much appreciated!

Comment: @BugFinder Without code this question is off-topic on code review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw i meant - when asked correctly :p sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I did it! Here's my code... I still dont understand some things about it...
It all started working when i changed all || operators to |

Please tell me if i can make this code better. Im new to unity and programming, so every bit of information is highly appreciated!

```
private void DestroyBlockBrush6(Vector3Int blockPos)
   {
       int brushSize = 13;
       bool killBlock = false;
       int indent = -1;

       int currBlockX = blockPos.x - brushSize / 2;
       int currBlockY = blockPos.y - brushSize / 2;
       int currBlockZ = blockPos.z - brushSize / 2;

       for (int z = 0; z < brushSize; z++, currBlockZ++)
       {
           for (int y = 0; y < brushSize; y++, currBlockY++)
           {
               indent = SetIndent(y, z);

               for (int x = 0; x < brushSize; x++, currBlockX++)
               {
                   if (indent >= 0)
                   {
                       if ((x >= indent) && (x < brushSize - indent))
                       {
                           killBlock = true;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           killBlock = false;
                       }
                   }

                   if ((currBlockX >= 0 && currBlockX < ChunkWidth) &&
                       (currBlockY >= 0 && currBlockY < ChunkHeight) &&
                       (currBlockZ >= 0 && currBlockZ < ChunkLength) && killBlock)
                   {
                       Blocks[currBlockX, currBlockY, currBlockZ] = 0;
                   }
               }
               currBlockX -= brushSize;
           }
           currBlockY -= brushSize;
       }

       //Blocks[7, 0, 0] = 1; 
       // IDONT KNOW WHAT CAN I DO ABOUT THIS BUG :)

       static int SetIndent(int y, int z)
       {
           if ((z == 0 | z == 12) && (y > 2 && y < 10)) return 3;

           if ((z == 1 | z == 11) && (y == 2 | y == 10)) return 3;
           if ((z == 1 | z == 11) && (y > 2 && y < 10)) return 2;

           if ((z == 2 | z == 10) && (y == 1 | y == 11)) return 3;
           if ((z == 2 | z == 10) && (y == 2 | y == 10)) return 2;
           if ((z == 2 | z == 10) && (y > 2 && y < 10)) return 1;

           if ((z >= 3 && z <= 9) && (y == 0 | y == 12)) return 3;
           if ((z >= 3 && z <= 9) && (y == 2 | y == 10)) return 1;
           if ((z >= 3 && z <= 9) && (y == 1 | y == 11)) return 2;
           if ((z >= 3 && z <= 9) && (y > 2 && y < 10)) return 0;

           return -1;
       }
**strong text**
       RegenerateMesh();
   }
```